# codeigniter where to put first page

Tags: php, codeigniter, ldap

I want to use code igniter, however I don't know where to put my initial login page,

I want it to be outside of the folder containing the rest of the code, because user will require ldap authentication to access it. However this initial login page needs to be displayed to all users.  What is the best way to do this in code igniter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this schema:

- a user controller `/application/controllers/user.php` which will handle signin/up/out
- a signin view in `/application/controllers/signin.php` which will be included from your signin method of your controller with `$this->load->view('signin')`
- a LDAP library in `/application/library/LDAP.php` that you will use in your controller to manage your secured connexion layer.

If you want to restict access to an other controller, just put somethign like `if (!$this->LDAP->is_logged()) ...` in your controller `__construct`.

Comment: I want something strictly to do with the directory structure, as in I want the initial sign in screen where the index.php page is or something like that